# Which mixed numbers have the property $\sqrt{n + \frac{p}{q}}=n\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$?

Tags: radicals

Could I please have help with describing mixed numbers (aka [mixed fractions](http://www.mathsisfun.com/mixed-fractions.html)) that have this property:

Show that $\sqrt{9\frac{9}{80}}=9\sqrt{\frac{9}{80}}$ and $\sqrt{4\frac{4}{15}}=4\sqrt{\frac{4}{15}},\;$ where $\sqrt{9\frac{9}{80}} = \sqrt{9+\frac{9}{80}}$ etc.

I can easily show this mathematically but however, which mixed numbers have this property and which don't, is there a rule, etc.

Comment: $$\sqrt{9\frac{9}{80}} = 9\sqrt{\frac{9}{80}}$$

Is not true, and neither is the other equality. $$\sqrt{9\frac{9}{80}}=\sqrt 9 \sqrt{\frac9{80}} = 3\sqrt{\frac{9}{80}}$$

Comment: No, it's true. Remember that it's a mixed number, not $9*\frac{9}{80}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

For $x,y\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$
$$\begin{align}\sqrt{x\dfrac{x}{y}} &= x\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}}\\ &\iff \\\sqrt{x+\dfrac{x}{y}}&=\sqrt{\dfrac{x^3}{y}}\\\sqrt{\dfrac{\color{blue}{x(y+1)}}{y}} &=\sqrt{\dfrac{\color{blue}{x^3}}{y}}\end{align}$$

Comparing you get $$\color{blue}{y = x^2-1}$$

That means it works for all $x,y$ that satisfy above equation

---

Check [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/mixed-fractions.html) for mixed numbers notation

Comment: +1, but how is this a "hint"?

Comment: Oops! Haha I changed my mind halfway through the hint XD Let me delete the word HINT!